# OpenCV works but PyCharm can't find referances

Tags: python, opencv, pycharm

I've just starting OpenCV tutorial. But previously I've installed it. The modules work properly, but PyCharm doesn't display any documentation of them and display a warning message:

> Cannot find reference 'imread' in '__init__.py'

Note 1: I'm using Python 3.5.2 and version of the OpenCV is 3.2 (I checked it from python terminal)

Note 2: Python terminal (Inside the PyCharm IDE) displays doc.

[image: Screenshot of the situation]

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this? I'm having this problem and wondering whether there is a fix?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `import cv2`

Use `from cv2 import cv2`

Answer (score -1):

**Hope this will help you**

1. when cv2.imshow() in give me this information"Cannot find reference 'imshow' in 'init.py | init.py'". 'imshow' is deprecated, still you can compile it and it works.
2. Make sure that you have given the correct file and folder name from where you are going to load the image.

> And please do not change the ' **init**.py ' file.